# MYSQL - Error Code: 1242 subquery returns more than 1 rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

The query is trying to return **all the roles** from lprovider table for a given provider if his role is not ExternalHealthCoach. If his role is ExternalHealthCoach then return ExternalHealthCoach as provider's role.

```
select
 role
from lprovider
where provider_id = 63 and
role in (select case when role = 'ExternalHealthCoach' then role
                else (select distinct role from lprovider) end from lprovider);
```

Sample records in Lprovider table:

role_column

ExternalHealthCoach

InternalHealthCoach

Doctor

FrontDesk

Admin

Co-ordinator

If the provider_id = X and if he is not ExternalHealthCoach then I want to return **all the roles** not a just only doctor.

Ex:
If provider_id = 63 and his role = doctor then the query should return all the roles in the lprovider table. i.e.

ExternalHealthCoach, InternalHealthCoach, Doctor, FrontDesk, Admin, Co-ordinator

But getting an error while executing. 
Error Code: 1242 subquery returns more than 1 rows

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` *expression` returns one value, not a list of values.

I think the logic you want is:

```
select l.role
from lprovider l
where l.provider_id = 63 and
      (l.role = 'Rejuvalyte-ExternalHealthCoach' or
       l.role in (select l2.role from lprovider l2) 
      );
```

Note that `select distinct` is not needed when using `in` with a subquery.

This logic is still a bit confusing.  I don't think the `in` part of the condition does anything.  You can just remove it.

Comment: the query is only returning doctor role. I want to return all the roles for a provider if he is not ExternalHealthCoach.